# Что такое API и на чем его писать?

Tags: api

Требуется сделать так, чтобы по ссылке вроде: `<script href="https://name.ru/api/?key=123456789"></script>` подключался JS код. При том на серверной части, домен с которого идёт запрос по ссылке нужно проверять в БД и сравнивать, что-то вроде защиты от распространения.
Если я правильно понимаю, это называется API, так вот хотелось бы узнать, прав ли я, и попросить совет на каком языке лучше писать API и может есть на примете книга/курс с обучалкой по написанию подобного API.

Comment: АПИ практически ничем не отличается от обычного сайта, за исключением формата обмена данными, который в большей степени рассчитан на обработку машиной, а не человеком. Соответственно АПИ вы можете писать на любом языке, на котором разрабатывают сайты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Что такое API?

API - Application Programming Interface - интерфейс программирования приложений (иногда - интерфейс прикладного программирования).

Интерфейс - это средство для взаимодействия между некоторыми программными или аппаратными сущностями. Например, есть физический интерфейс Ethernet, который служит для взаимодействия двух соседних аппаратных устройств. Есть интерфейс TCP/IP, с помощью которого могут взаимодействовать программы, находящиеся на различных компьютерах, подключённых к сети Интернет (на одном компьютере тоже могут быть). Есть интерфейсы как средства языка программирования - которые описывают, что должен уметь делать класс, реализующий данный интерфейс.

Под интерфейсом программирования приложений обычно понимают средство для взаимодействия клиентского приложения с некоторым сервисом. Например, существует Windows API, обращаясь к функциям которого, приложение может запросить у операционной системы её ресурсы: открыть файл, создать окно, узнать время и т.д.

Отдельным классом стоит API веб-сервисов. Оно позволяет некоторым приложениям (например, ботам социальных сетей) отправлять к серверу запросы заранее определённого формата и возвращать ответы, которые будут понятны этому приложению.

### Как писать API?

В настоящее время наиболее популярным форматом веб-сервисом является REST API. Этот формат заключается в том, что сервер предоставляет разработчикам специальный файл, написанный на языке Open API, в котором описаны функции, которые может выполнять данный сервер ([см. пример файла](https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json)). В файле описан формат всех возможных запросов, перечень параметров каждого запроса, формат ответа на каждый запрос, подробное описание всех возвращаемых данных.

Примеру файла, приведённому выше, соответствует интерфейс магазина домашних животных - это базовый пример для демонстрации возможностей REST API. Существует инструмент **Swagger**, с помощью которого можно визуализировать интерфейс, описанный в файле, и попытаться выполнить запросы с помощью [веб-страницы](https://petstore.swagger.io/#/). С помощью того же Swagger можно сгенерировать код клиента и сервера на многих языках.

### ИТОГ

Вам нужно:

1. Описать интерфейс веб-сервиса на языке Open API;
2. Сгенерировать код сервера;
3. Развернуть сервер где-нибудь;
4. Сгенерировать код клиента.
5. Пользоваться.

Comment: Слово класс, никак неуместно в ответе, т.к. интерфейс это описание взаимодействия а не ее реализация.

Comment: @Kotomi, собственно, у меня так и написано: интерфейс - описание того, что умеет делать класс, реализующий его. А с другой стороны, интерфейс - это класс, содержащий только чисто виртуальные методы. И нигде я не упомянул про реализацию.

Comment: Дело не в этом... А в том что это не должен быть никакой класс... Это вообще могут быть просто функции, запросы, да что угодно кроме классов. Это интерфейс, то через что взаимодействует разработчик.